# Passenger (Apache) on EC2 not loading Rails application when arrive via DNS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, amazon-ec2, dns, passenger

This is driving me nuts. Hopefully someone can help

I've deployed a Rails app on an EC2 instance (Ubuntu) using Apache and Passenger. Here's my Apache configuration on the EC2 instance

> **/etc/apache2/apache2.conf**

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName ec2-52-16-160-160.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
   # !!! Be sure to point DocumentRoot to 'public'!
   DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/workspace/intellitute/public
   ErrorLog /home/ubuntu/workspace/intellitute/log/error.log
   RailsEnv development

   <Directory /home/ubuntu/workspace/intellitute/public>
     # This relaxes Apache security settings.
     AllowOverride all
     Require all granted
     # MultiViews must be turned off.
     Options -MultiViews
   </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

This works and I'm able to access the application by putting ec2-52-16-160-160.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com into a browser.

I've registered a domain name with a provider (not AWS) and set up two 'A' DNS records there (appname.com & *.appname.com) to point at the public ip of my server - 52.16.160.160.

I've then changed the ServerName in the conf file above to the domain name I registered and restarted the Apache server.

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.appname.com  (also tried 'ServerName appname.com')
  .....
```

But when I type www.appname.com into a browser I'm just getting the Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page. I'm assuming the fact I'm getting the default page means the DNS is working but for some reason Passenger is not loading the application? Is this assumption correct?

Does it make a difference that I'm still working in the development environment?

I'm stuck and can't find any solution.

Thanks for looking

> **Edit 1**

I'm not at my development machine at the moment but does it make a difference that I haven't set up an elastic IP address on my EC2 instance? I'm just using the public IP address provided by the instance.  I'll try set one up later to see what happens.

Comment: Tried `ServerName appname.com` also but it's just not working. I'm getting the default apache page but the Rails app is not loading. Tried everything at this stage. Very frustrating

Comment: Anyone any suggestions? I'm pretty stumped here. Are my settings in the conf file ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured this out. Might help someone in the future.

My EC2 instance was a clone of another and I reckon there was some issues with the apache2 and passenger configurations. I uninstalled and re-installed them on the EC2 instance and it is now working (for appname.com, not www.appname.com - I'll have to figure that out)